# Apache Commons CLI: replacement for deprecated OptionBuilder?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

IntelliJ shows that OptionBuilder is deprecated in this example code from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html.

What should I use as the replacement?

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

Options options = new Options();
options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withLongOpt( "block-size" )
       .withDescription( "use SIZE-byte blocks" )
       .hasArg()
       .withArgName("SIZE")
       .create());
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/index.html

> Deprecated.  since 1.3, use Option.builder(String) instead

This is the replacement:

```
Options options = new Options();
Option option = Option.builder("a")
    .longOpt( "block-size" )
    .desc( "use SIZE-byte blocks"  )
    .hasArg()
    .argName( "SIZE" )
    .build();
options.addOption( option );
```

Comment: Note: if you're having trouble with this via groovy, it might be because you're using java 7. When I used a java 7 runtime with commons-cli-1.4.jar I'd get `signature of method: static org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder() is applicable for argument types`

Answer (score 2):

Use the (inner) class `Option.Builder` as in

```
Option option = Option.builder("a")
 .required(true)
 .longOpt("arg-name")
 .build();
```

Cf. [Option.Builder Java-Doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html). I.e. the static `builder()` method of `Option` returns an `Option.Builder` and the trailing call to `build()` gives you an `Option`.